# Trying to make a button switch between two different values

Tags: javascript, toggle, visibility

I don't know if this is some sort of loop protection, but I want a button that when clicked toggles an image on or off and this code is not working:

```
<script>                            
document.getElementById('standbybutton').onclick = function() {                         
if (document.querySelector('#standby img').style.visibility = 'hidden'){                                
document.querySelector('#standby img').style.visibility = 'visible'                         
} else {                                
document.querySelector('#standby img').style.visibility = 'hidden'                          
} return false; 
}                   
</script>
```

What am I missing? If the image is hidden, make it visible. If else, make it hidden. No?

Comment: Are you seeing errors? Post your HTML code too else we really can't debug it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator (`=`) and not a comparison operator (`==` or `===`).

EDIT: Just FYI, JSLint (or something similar) would have caught this.